# remove space from path

Tags: batch-file

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
localDirectoryPath=d:/folder/subfolder
set /p AHFilename=<%fileName%
set pathname=!localDirectoryPath!\!AHFilename!
echo pathname=!pathname!
```

pathname when echoed,output is `d:/folder/subfolder /fileName` , that is there is space between subfolder and / , hence path of pathname becomes inaccessible. the error shown on command prompt is "d:/folder/subfolder" does not exist.

Please help. If the said space is removed, the code may run correct.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have a space at end of this line: `localDirectoryPath=d:/folder/subfolder`, just remove it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you do not have a space after this line: `localDirectoryPath=d:/folder/subfolder

I'm no batch knowledge guy, but does your code even run? I'm missing the setting of the %fileName% variable, I think you're missing a SET call in front of the second line and you should replace the \ with a / in the "set pathname"  line. I think... Should it not be something like this:?

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET localDirectoryPath=d:/folder/subfolder
set fileName=d:/someFile.txt
set /p AHFilename=<%fileName%
set pathname=!localDirectoryPath!\!AHFilename!
echo pathname=!pathname!
```

Answer (score 1):

Works Ok for me as is, except for a couple typos:

- -you need 'set' to make the localdirectorypath declaration work.
- -you've mixed back slashes and forward slashes in your localdirectory and pathname.

  Choose one.  What filesystem are you using?
- -Using redirection when setting AHFilename will give you mixed results.

The corrected code that is working for me on a Windows XP device:

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set localDirectoryPath=c:\folder\subfolder
set /p AHFilename=%fileName%
set pathname=!localDirectoryPath!\!AHFilename!
echo pathname=!pathname!
```

If this still isnt working for you, you can encapsulate the variable and data with quotes:

```
set "localDirectoryPath=c:\folder\subfolder"
```

If this still isnt working, you can strip the final character from the localdirectorypath data at the point you are using it:

```
set pathname=!localDirectoryPath:~0,-1!\!AHFilename!
echo pathname=!pathname!
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the code you have posted cannot possibly run. And it certainly cannot introduce a space between `subfolder` and `\`.

But, if you do have a variable that has unwanted spaces at the end of a folder and/or file name, it is very easy to get rid of them.

Windows does not allow the last character of a file or folder name to be a dot or a space - Windows will strip trailing dots and spaces from the name if you attempt to create it. But commands like DIR will not ignore trailing space.

```
D:\>mkdir "my folder "

D:\>dir "my folder "
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8FD-5039

 Directory of D:\my folder

File Not Found

D:\>dir "my folder"
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8FD-5039

 Directory of D:\my folder

03/29/2012  06:00 PM    <DIR>          .
03/29/2012  06:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  67,054,551,040 bytes free
```

You can use parameter or FOR variable modifiers to trim erroneous trailing dots or spaces from path names. The modifiers will transform the name into a standard format, including stripping trailing dots and/or spaces from each folder name within the path.

```
@echo off
set "myVar=my folder "
echo this will fail because of space at end of path
dir "%myVar%"
echo(
echo The ~f modifier strips the trailing space
for %%F in ("%myVar%") do dir "%%~fF"
```

Here are the results of the above script

```
this will fail because of space at end of path
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8FD-5039

 Directory of D:\my folder

File Not Found

The ~f modifier strips the trailing space
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8FD-5039

 Directory of D:\my folder

03/29/2012  06:00 PM    <DIR>          .
03/29/2012  06:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  67,054,551,040 bytes free
```

Comment: FYI:  and unrelated to the heart of your message - It is possible to create a file with a space at the end.  Most sysadmins need to solve this problem from time to time - See http://serverfault.com/questions/225276/batch-file-code-to-find-and-rename-all-files-ending-in-a-space/230958#230958

Comment: @RobW - Wow, very interesting (and nasty). Thanks for the info. What is that \\?\ syntax at the beginning of the redirection path in the link? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @dbenham check this out...
http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/windowspaths.html